# Is there any graph API to update the user's status inside msteams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to update the Microsoft Teams user's status via an API so is there any graph API for that.

Comment: Not yet but this feature has been already requested by users.https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/39651298-microsoft-graph-presence-api.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question is "NO".
currently there is no api that allows you to update the user's current status in Teams.